# Adding where 'id IN ' clause to Model with addCondition()

Tags: atk4

I was wondering if I can use addCondition() to add a where clause of the type: 'id IN (1,2,3,4)' to an existing model? according to the comments in Model_Tabel it would need to be possible if I give it an DB_dsql instance:

```
function addCondition($field,$cond=undefined,$value=undefined)
{
    // You may pass plain "dsql" expressions as a first argument
    if($field instanceof DB_dsql && $cond==undefined && $value==undefined){
        $this->_dsql()->where($field);
    return $this;
}
```

but If I try to do this:

```
$conflicto=$this->add('Model_Conflicto');
$conflicto->addCondition($this->api->db->dsql()->where('id IN'.$str));
```

I get an invalid SQL statement, which includes the whole select in the new where clause:

select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,`conflicto`.`id` from `conflicto` where (select * where id IN(14, 60, 37, 39, 41, 43, 52, 57, 141, 144, 145, 183, 187, 14) )

I'm probably doing something really wrong here?
what would be the correct way to include 'where id IN ' to get this to work with my model?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
$model->addCondition('id',array(14,60,37,....));
```